# How to pop back on previous screen from alert and send there a value?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

The questions I'm going to ask are really connected. The idea is pop back on previous screen from alert and send there a value, but as it turned out there are some difficulties with it.
I use `cool_alert` package in these pieces.

1. I can show alert, but how after it pop back on previous screen and send a value?

> ```
> onPressed: () {
>     ...
>     _coolAlert(context);
> },
> ```

2. 

if I use the following then why the alert even doesn't show?

> ```
> onPressed: () {
>     ...
>     _coolAlert(context);
>     Navigator.pop(context, true);
> },
> ```

where _coolAlert defined as

> ```
> _coolAlert(Build Context context) {
>     CoolAlert.show(
>        context: context,
>        type: CoolAlertType.success,
>        text: "Your transaction was successful!",
>        onConfirmBtnTap: () {
>            debugPrint('success');
>        },
>     );
> }
> ```

the return type of `show` is `Future<dynamic>`

3. and finally if change it like this, then why the receiving value on previous screen is null?

> ```
> _coolAlert(Build Context context) {
>   CoolAlert.show(
>      context: context,
>      type: CoolAlertType.success,
>      text: "Your transaction was successful!",
>      onConfirmBtnTap: () {
>          debugPrint('success');
>      },
>      Navigator.pop(context, true);
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more param which is need for this to work.

`closeOnConfirmBtnTap: false,`

This will allow you to manually call `pop` method with a value. Here is a sample code

```dart
import 'package:cool_alert/cool_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const CoolAlertExample());
}

class CoolAlertExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const CoolAlertExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Cool Alert Example')),
        body: _HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final result = await Navigator.of(context).push<bool?>(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => _MyPage(),
                ),
              ) ??
              false;

          print('HomePage: result = $result');
        },
        child: const Text('Next page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
            final result = await CoolAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: CoolAlertType.success,
              text: "Your transaction was successful!",
              closeOnConfirmBtnTap: false,
              onConfirmBtnTap: () {
                // return from dialog with success
                debugPrint('success');
                navigator.pop(true);
              },
              onCancelBtnTap: () {
                // return from dialog with cancel
                debugPrint('cancel');
                navigator.pop(false);
              },
            );

            print('returned from cool dialog = $result');

            //return to home page with value retuned from cool dialog.
            navigator.pop<bool>(result);
          },
          child: const Text('Show Alert'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
flutter: success
flutter: returned from cool dialog = true
flutter: HomePage: result = true
```

Comment: this is the answer I was really looking for

Answer (score 0):

bool? callBack= await _coolAlert(context);
Cuz dialog returns future, you have to wait for it

Answer (score 0):

simply add await

[image]

```
import 'package:cool_alert/cool_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const NewPage(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('new page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await CoolAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: CoolAlertType.success,
              text: "Your transaction was successful!",
              onConfirmBtnTap: () {
                debugPrint('success');
              },
            );
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('alert and pop'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in your code

2.

```
onPressed: () async {
    ...
    await_coolAlert(context);
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
},
```

3. 

```
  Future<void> _coolAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return CoolAlert.show(
      context: context,
      type: CoolAlertType.success,
      text: "Your transaction was successful!",
      onConfirmBtnTap: () {
        debugPrint('success');
      },
    );
  }
```